# getting the maximum value of each group after groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe and I want to groupby city and country and get the city with higher pop in each group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Brasil', 'Brasil' , 'EUA', 'EUA'],
                  'city': ['Santos', 'São Paulo', 'Orlando', 'Nova York'],
                  'pop': [100000, 500000, 200000, 550000]})
df
```

What I want:

country    city     pop 
Brasil  São Paulo  500000
EUA     Nova York  550000

What I have already done:

```
df.groupby(['country','city']).loc[df.pop == df.pop.max()]
```

Python returns: "AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

I know that I must use apply, but I still don´t understand the logic of it in python. Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: `df.groupby(['country','city'],as_index = False)['pop'].max()`?

Comment: @ansev I said it worked but I was wrong. This didn´t change my output

Comment: `df =df.groupby(['country','city'],as_index = False)['pop'].max()`